# Schedule a crontab edit

Tags: cron, schedule

Is it possible to schedule a crontab edit?

I mean, for example, tomorrow at 10 AM I want to schedule something.

Is there a way to crontab a script that tomorrow will edit crontab (scheduling something)?

I know that this question could seem stupid (in fact obviously I can just schedule in crontab the script now or tomorrow but it is just a curiosity if there is a way to schedule the crontab edit)

Maybe I can just schedule a script calling it CRONTAB_EDIT.sh that will run tomorrow at 9 59 AM something that will edit /var/spool/cron/crontabs and will schedule what I want making me happy.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Many things are *possible*, but still the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What should I use with and without installing some other packages?

Comment: Systemd timers, /etc/cron.d, and atjobs are all available to you right now without installing any new packages. For a one-off job, use `at`. For scheduled jobs you want to turn off-and-on, use either of the others. We can give you less abstract advice if you provide a less abstract example.

Comment: Ok let's say that i use at command for a one-off job. The at syntax is like this : at -f my_at_test.sh 9:59 I want that my_at_test edit the crontab. What should my_at_test.sh contain?

Comment: See `man at` for complete instructions.

Comment: The current question, as written, seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm reading it.

Answer (score 3):

You should not edit files in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directly. The correct procedure to do so is:

1. get current crontab with the command `crontab -l >file`
2. modify the output file using any means, eg. `sed`, perl etc.
3. apply new crontab with the command `crontab file`

If you are doing this for a different user than yourself (you must be root for this of course), add `-u username` parameter after the `crontab` command.

You can write a script that performs the above points 1-3 and schedule it using the `at` command as said in comments.